# Java swing Border and Boxlayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, jbutton

i have a Jtable and now i want to have a JLabel and a JTextField and a JButton in one row
above this Jtable.

How do i do that?

until now i had this:

```
    final JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

now i added this above:

```
    ImageIcon leftButtonIcon = createImageIcon("images/add.gif");
    JButton addButton = new JButton(leftButtonIcon);

    JLabel labelF = new JLabel("Filter:");
    labelF.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

    JTextField eingabeF = new JTextField();
    eingabeF.setSize(50, 10);
```

but how to do, that there ist this: "Filter: TEXTFIELD BUTTON"
and under this there is the Table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the `labelF` label, `eingabeF` text field and `addButton` button to an instance of `JPanel` with `FLowLayout`. And add it to the content pane(which has `BorderLayout`) with constraint `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`. `JPanel` has `FlowLayout` as it's default layout
2. Enclose your table to an instance of `JScrollPane` and Then add the scroll pane to the content pane with constraint `BorderLayout.CENTER`. The scroll pane automatically places the *table header* at the top of the viewport.

   ```
   JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
   table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
   ```

Comment: how to add it to the content pane ? my contentpane:    final Table newContentPane = new Table();
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

Comment: well, it is the frame.getContentPane().add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER) :) component can be any component: JPanel/JTable?JScrollPane. Enclose your table to a JScrollPane as i have written in the answe

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just one question: i can't type anything in my textfield, because it has a width of about 0 px :D Do you know why? also when i do this: eingabeF.setSize(500, 100);

Comment: @progNewFag, i forgot to mention, flow layout obeys component's preferred size. So set the preferred size of `textFeild`. `setColumn(int)` method will also do. Alternatively you can also create it: `new JTextField(" ", columnCount)`;

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. How can i insert a Row, by clicking the button ? I have already written the actionhandler and it works well, but how can i access the tablemodel from my jpanel instance where the button is placed?

Comment: `TableModel` associates with `Table`. So you can ask the table model from the `table` instance by `table.getModel()` function. `JTable` uses `DefaultTableModel` as default model. [Check this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)